# Laravel 5: Uploaded image not being attached to article_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to upload an image when creating an article and have that image be attached to the article so I can do something like `{{ $article->image->path }}` in my view. So far, everything is set up good and the article gets saved to the correct directory and the path gets added to the database (although the path is strange, for example a file named "moon-wallpaper" will be saved as "img/moon-wallpaper.jpg.jpg" -- it adds the extension twice for some reason). But anyways..

The problem in my question is that the image path that was saved to the images table should have an article_id attached to it to be referenced in the view... but I get an error and the error says "trying to get property of non object" because `$response->id` in the store method evaluates to null =S what am I doing wrong? How can I do this correctly?

Any help would be great!

store method in Articles Controller:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $this->createArticle($request);

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $uploads = 'img/';

        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $image->move($uploads, $imageName);

        $response =  $this->createArticle($request);

        Image::create([
            'path' => $uploads.$imageName,
            'article_id' => $response->id
        ]);

        return redirect('blog');
    }
```

using a private method to create the article. createArticle method:

```
private function createArticle(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article = Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());

        $this->syncTags($article, $request->input('tag_list'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you create the article 2 times? The second time you store the value returned by createArticle() method in $response, but this method doesn't return any value. You should return $article after syncTags().

```
private function createArticle(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());

    $this->syncTags($article, $request->input('tag_list'));

    return $article;
}
```

Am I right?

Comment: I have $this->createArticle($request); and then return redirect('blog'); in the store method. That saves an article (minus all of that other image code). Just used the method to clean it up I guess.

Comment: If you put dd($response); before the line in which you create the image, what does $response have?

Comment: $response has null =\

Comment: yeah, I know. That's why in my answer I said you should add "return $article" in the createArticle() method. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, it fixed the problem as far as no longer getting an error. But the path is added to images table and article_id is still 0. But this time when I dd $response I get the ArticleRequest object which comes with a whole bunch of stuff that I'm not looking for lol

Comment: Do you have article_id in the $fillable property in the Image model? Should be an array with the fields that can be filled by the create method

Comment: Ah, that would be it! Thanks! Forgot to add that to the mass assignable array.

Comment: Now another problem, haha. {{ $article->images }} returns an empty array, {{ $article->images->path }} returns an error "undefined property", that being $path. Am I calling this wrong? This is within my index method, just showing all articles.

Comment: haha how did you write your relationship between article and images? Remember to check your images data. The first line in your store method creates an article. Then you do some image manipulation and create ANOTHER article, and save the image with it's id. The first article doesn't have any image. So if you iterate through articles, you should check: if($article->images). If not null, iterate on each image and get the path

Comment: I have return Article::with('images')->findOrFail($id); in my routeserviceprovider for route model binding, and in the view when I do $article->images I get a collection. How can I get just one image path? $article->images->path gives undefined property error

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can do $article->images->first()->path to get the path of the first image